# Command is working on terminal but not giving syntax error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

Below is my script placed in /usr/bin as I want to make it available globally

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /app/data/zips
rm -rf -i -v !(*.zip)
cd /app/cronscripts/import
> import_output.log
nohup ./import.sh > import_output.log & disown
```

Everything in the above script is working perfectly fine apart from the below-given line, however, this command is working perfectly fine when running it from the terminal directly. It's for deleting all files and folders except .zip files in the directory

```
rm -rf -i -v !(*.zip)
```

Whenever I try to run this script it gives me the following error.

```
/usr/bin/importdata.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/importdata.sh: line 3: `rm -rf -i -v !(*.zip)'
```

My which bash output is:

```
/bin/bash
```

OS information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: If I were you I'd just do a `find /app/data/zips -depth  \! -name "*.zip" -exec rm -rf -i -v '{}' +`.

Comment: How do you run your script ? It's like you ran it with `sh script.sh` instead of using `bash`

Comment: This is to replace the first two lines after the line with `#!/bin/bash`. What it does is find all files or directories in /app/data/zips that do NOT (the !) have the name *.zip and perform on them the action of `rm ...`.

Comment: `man find` can be your friend.

Comment: @GillesQuenot: I run like just script.sh

Comment: @Roadowl: Thanks for your valuable feedback I will try and get back.

Comment: Anytime you use `cd` in a script, you need some sort of error checking on it -- if the `cd` fails for some reason, the rest of the script will execute in the wrong place, with potentially dangerous results. Suppose that `rm` command ran in the wrong place!

Comment: How can i check cd error?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz Personally, I prefer not to `cd` in scripts at all; instead, use explicit paths, like `rm -rf -i -v /app/data/zips/!(*.zip)`, `> /app/cronscripts/import/import_output.log`, etc. When I need to `cd`, I like to use something like `cd /somedir || { echo "Error changing directory" >&2; exit 1; }` (see [BashPitfalls #19](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cd_.2Ffoo.3B_bar)). BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash`, `!(pattern)` is an extended glob pattern. Turn on the shell option which enables that:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

`shopt` should appear on its own line at the start of the script, along with any other options which you may be relying on. See *wooledge*: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Options_which_change_globbing_behavior

> `extglob` changes the way certain characters are parsed. It is necessary to have a newline (not just a semicolon) between `shopt -s extglob` and any subsequent commands to use it. You cannot enable extended globs inside a group command that uses them, because the entire block is parsed before the `shopt` is *evaluated*.